# Add overlap or duplicate pixels on texture bounds after cropping in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, textures

I have huge texture Nx1024 pixels. I split it into several 1024x1024 textures with the following command with Imagemagick:

```
magick image.png -quality 100 -background none -resize x1024 -crop 1024x1024 -extent 1024x1024 output%02d.png
```

How can I add 2 pixels overlap on left and right sides of output images or duplicate pixels with imagemagick?

PS: 
I found the following case (-crop 3x1+2@) [crop with equal size](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal) but it doesn't suit because I have an unknown width of the input image (it could be multiple of N for 1024)

Comment: I am not quite sure of what you are asking or doing with your code but out of interest you probably do not need the convert as you have magick. The input image should come first after magick and the -quality just before the save. I do not see why you are using a -distort resize rather than just a -resize and in your case Lanczos is probably the default filter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will simplify my command. I just want to duplicate pixels or make some overlap on borders for the following concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on Unix-based OS, then you could try my script, overlapcrop at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php